# How to connect Node.js with saleforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, node.js

Actually i wanted to connect Node.js with saleforce for chat system withing salesforce.

Can any body help me or give me any idea that how to achieve this function, i researched over google for saleforce and Node.js but didn't find any luck.

Comment: Did you really search? The first and second things that come up for me when I google "Node.js Salesforce" is [jsForce](https://github.com/jsforce/jsforce)

Comment: It is not that hard to find information then ask if you hit a problem - see [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use Salesforce APIs to connect Node.js to salesforce, check solution link below:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-salesforce

Some useful links:

http://www.redargyle.com/blog/introduction-node-js-salesforce/

http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2012/04/27/node-js-demo-with-force-com-rest-api-oauth-express/